# Eclipse JSP: incorrect default text file encoding

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I've got the following problem. I created a new "Dynamic Web Project" and imported some existing jsp files into it.

If i right click one of the imported jsp files and click "Properties" > "Resource" then under the "Text file encoding" section a value of "Default (determined by content type: ISO-8859-1)". However i have runned iconv before importing to assure they're in utf-8:

```
$ iconv -f "ISO-8859-1" -t "UTF-8" from.jsp > to.jsp
```

All the jsp files has the following meta set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Does anybody know how to change this setting? Tomcat is serving them correctly as utf-8 (http content-type header), so i don't really know in what this impacts...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature

Eclipse didn't "determine" the correct encoding by scanning the file as like file or iconv commands on your shell.

**Solution:** Add following line to your JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

This is a good Idea due to many Web-Container will force to deliver ISO-8859-1 encoded files nevertheless you have set the correct content type in your HTML Header.

*FYI: Mismatching CharacterSets and file encodings will lead*

- to characters like in "Schei� encoding" (Latin1 character in UTF8 (multiByte) context).
- If you got something like "fÃ¼r" it is indead a broken multibyte character (typically UTF-8) in a singleByte character context (Latin1 / ISO-8859-1 || ISO-8859-15 for Germans)

Comment: Repling a bit late :) Thanks, that solved the issue!... I'm still lost about why, because all the configuration pointed by the other replies looks good (all of them saying utf-8).

Comment: hi @roirodriguez never mind about late reply, glad to help you .. but yes, this encoding stuff is still annoying and you might seldomly trust the obvious settings ;/

Answer (score 11):

Windows >Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP > Default Encoding > UTF-8

Comment: Thank you so much! :-) Why the hell are there at least three settings in three different locations for this simple thing?! ;-)

Comment: as mentioned in my answer: This might help in eclipse, but might then break (again) in the runtime context because of encoding is unclear

Answer (score 1):

What are the encoding settings in `Window > Preferences` `General > Workspace`, `Web > JSP Files` and in the `Project Properties > Resource`? They all have to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to Windows -> Preferences -> Web -> JSP Files

Select UTF-8 encoding from the *Encoding *dropdown box there.