# Charset, encoding of JSP file in eclipse still ISO-8859-1?

Tags: eclipse, file, jsp, encoding

I manually changed the default encoding of a JSP file to UTF-8, but when I create a new file with template ${encoding}, the `charset` is always set to `ISO-8859-1`.

How do I change eclipse's setting so that UTF-8 is the default charset for JSP files?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem but changed the settings here:

```
Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> 
Text -> JSP -> Default Encoding -> UTF-8
```

It worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16):

I think you are asking how do you set the template so that ${encoding} will print out `UTF-8`, rather than `ISO-8859-1`.

If that's the case, you need to follow:

```
Window-->Preferences-->Web-->JSP Files
```

and then just use the drop down box to change to `ISO 10646/Unicode(UTF-8)`

You will also need to do the same thing for HTML files.

Answer (score 4):

perhaps the same "problem" as like in [Eclipse JSP: incorrect default text file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045413)

Add

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

to your JSP *AND* check the workspace encoding settings as described by Joe

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, go to Windows -> Preferences -> Web -> JSP Files

Select UTF-8 encoding from the *Encoding *dropdown box there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the encoding parameter has not been set to UTF-8 it needs to be changed from the source where it is coming.